# jquery plugin to edit table cells in place and save to file (also select diff kinds of inputs)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am generating a html table from a mysql query (generates a new flat html page)

Is there a plugin that i can use that will let me click/edit individual cells and save that data and refresh the content (important, cause i scrape the page and write to file later) but i also need to be able to select individual input types, some are simple text inputs, some are text areas, some are lists, etc.

In the mysql dump page, i can assign each column a class so if the plugin would use that to determine input type that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jeditable - Edit in place plugin for jQuery.](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)